# How can you find the polynomial for a decimated LFSR?

Tags: encryption

I know that it if you decimate the series generated by a linear feedback shift register, you get a new series and a new polynomial.  For example, if you sample every fifth element in the series generated by a LFSR with polynomial x<sup>4</sup>+x+1, you get the series generated by x<sup>2</sup>+x+1.  I can find the second polynomial (x<sup>2</sup>+x+1) by brute force, which is fine for low-order polynomials.  However, for higher-order polynomials, the time required to brute force it gets unreasonable.

So the question is: is it possible to find the decimated polynomial analytically?

Answer (score 1):

Recently read this article and thought of it when seeing your question, hope it helps.. :oÞ

Given a primitive polynomial over GF(q), one can obtain another primitive polynomial by decimating an LFSR sequence obtained from the initial polynomial. This is demonstrated in the code below.

> K := GF(7);
>   C := PrimitivePolynomial(K, 2);
>   C;
>   D^2 + 6*D + 3
>   In order to generate an LFSR sequence, we must first multiply this polynomial by a suitable constant so that the trailing coefficient becomes 1.
>
> C := C * Coefficient(C,0)^-1;
>   C;
>   5*D^2 + 2*D + 1
>   We are now able to generate an LFSR sequence of length 72 - 1. The initial state can be anything other than [0, 0].
>
> t := LFSRSequence (C, [K| 1,1], 48);
>   t; 
>   [ 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 6, 4, 4, 0, 1, 5, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 
>   0, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 6, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 1, 2, 5 ]
>   We decimate the sequence by a value d having the property gcd(d, 48)=1.
>
> t := Decimation(t, 1, 5);
>   t;
>   [ 1, 5, 0, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6, 2, 
>   0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 0, 3, 6, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 4, 2, 6, 6 ]
>   B := BerlekampMassey(t);
>   B;
>   3*D^2 + 5*D + 1
>   To get the corresponding primitive polynomial, we multiply by a constant to make it monic.
>
> B := B * Coefficient(B, 2)^-1;
>   B;
>   D^2 + 4*D + 5
>   IsPrimitive(B);
>   true

Answer (score 0):

from [these notes](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~hmiranda/cm/Pseudo_Noise_Sequences.pdf): "The decimation by n>0 of a m-sequence c , denoted as c[ n],
has a period equal to N/gcd(N,n), if it is not the all-zero
sequence, its generator polynomial gˆ( x ) has roots that are nth
powers of the roots of g(x)"